# Transparency and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to show a form when i click on edit button on the JTable. The form that is displayed should overlap the JTable and should darken the jTable (just like a black background with transparency). How do i do this ? Do i have to add the jPanel to the window during creation of JFrame or shall i create the panel as a separate file and make it visible when the button is clicked. Tell me how to do this ?

EDIT

Something similar to this

[image]

EDIT 2

You have used JOption pane and the other suggestion was to use JDialog. But if i use either of those i cant create child window. I just need to call virtual keyboard from the popped up Jdialog window. I cant access the keyboard as the JDialog is holding the focus. How to solve this issue ?

EDIT 3

The current problem is, i am using virtual keyboard for typing the values in the form displayed by using JDialog. Now i cant able to open the virtual Keyboard and make it active. Even if i open it it is behind the JDialog and the focus is still with JDialog. I need to close the JDialog for using the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Can you link to an image of the effect that you're trying to achieve?  As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words!  Luck!

Comment: check my edit. i have attached the image..

Comment: Please tell us more details about the new problem.

Comment: Is virtual keyboard a 3rd party library as I'm not familiar with it? Do you have a link to its site?  How do you use it?

Comment: no no i just created it normally. It is another JDialog with set of buttons in it.

Comment: You could make the above dialog non-modal, or you could display your virtual keyboard dialog as a modal dialog to the above dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little late in answering as I was creating a test program, but my idea is the same as Andrew's (sorry Andrew, and 1+ to Andrew):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DarkBackground extends JPanel {
   private static final Dimension MAIN_SIZE = new Dimension(800, 500);
   private static final Color DarkColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 60);
   private JComponent glassPane;

   public DarkBackground() {
      JButton showDialogBtn = new JButton("Show Dialog");
      showDialogBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            setGlassPaneVisible(true);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DarkBackground.this, "Foo");
            setGlassPaneVisible(false);
         }
      });
      add(showDialogBtn);
      setPreferredSize(MAIN_SIZE);

   }

   public void setGlassPane(JComponent glassPane) {
      JRootPane rootpane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(this);
      this.glassPane = glassPane; 

      rootpane.setGlassPane(glassPane);
   }

   public void setGlassPaneVisible(boolean visible) {
      glassPane.setVisible(visible);
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      DarkBackground darkBgrd = new DarkBackground();
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DarkBackground");
      frame.getContentPane().add(darkBgrd);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      darkBgrd.setGlassPane(new MyGlassPane(DarkColor));
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyGlassPane extends JComponent {
   private Color backgroundColor;

   public MyGlassPane(Color backgroundColor) {
      this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.setColor(backgroundColor);
      g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
   }
}
```

Comment: Now *that's* what I'm talkin' about (in vague, general terms).

Comment: thank you very much...  I used few parts of your code to fit my application. its working!!

Comment: I'd hate to nitpick here, but why not override the component's `getPreferredSize` method instead of calling `setPreferredSize` in the constructor?

Comment: Actually the nitpick should be why use preferredSize at all.  Far better would be to fill the GUI with components using appropriate layout managers and let the managers set the best size for all.  I did this just to make a nice big GUI to show the glasspane better. Other nitpicks include use of magic numbers, needlessly extending JPanel, and incorrect naming of a constant (not fully capitalized).  I could go on, but I won't. :)

Answer (score 4):

See [How to Use Root Panes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) in the Java Tutorial.  From the screen-shot it appears you need to pop a `JOptionPane` (or `JDialog`) for the input and draw the shading on the glass pane.

Comment: yes somethign similar to that. I need to popup a screen to get input. But i might have to use scrollbar as well because the form is pretty large or i might use tabbed panes. So is JOptionPane a right option ?

Comment: @Deepak "..is JOptionPane a right option ?"  You can put a `JPanel` in a `JOptionPane`.  The `JPanel` can include whatever it needs (including other `JPanels`, `JScrollPanes`, `JButtons`, `JLabels` etc.).  Sometimes you might need to specify **preferred** size for the components, especially a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Agree with Andrew.  A JOptionPane is the easiest way to display your dialog or a modal JDialog if you don't like the configuration of the JOptionPane buttons.